# Give single quote to each word in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

Hello I have very big list of such entries

```
7891,
7893,
7894,
60287,
71978,
40200,
11113,...
```

may be around 10000 records
I want to use them in SQL , but to use them in SQL I need to put single quote for each of this number like this

```
'7891',
'7893',
```

Is there any quick shortcut to do that.
Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use the replace function (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) use `Search Mode: Extended` , and replace all `,\r\n` with `',\r\n'` (and add a `'` at the beginning and end of course)

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,it worked like a charm for all 10000 records, Thank you so much. You are very intelligent.

Comment: This only answers the particular example here, but does not address the question of putting single quotes around words. Suppose there was more than one word on a line.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer:**

If you have these numbers in the same line, use replace (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), for search mode: `Regular expressions`, and replace all `(\d+)` with `'\1'`.

**Explanation:**

`\d` - A digit in the 0-9 range.

`+` - This matches 1 or more instances of the previous character, as many as it can. In our case it will match all digits unless other character.

`(\d+)` - Parentheses group that part of the regular expression together. We can later use this group by its number.

`'\1'` - We insert first found group into `''` characters.

To test regular expressions use https://regex101.com/r/nA8hQ3/1 (I prepared sample for you).

For more info about notepad++ regular expression syntax please visit http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions.

Answer (score 0):

To put single quotes around words, use this regex.

```
 Regex.Replace( string.Join(",",items),@"(\w+)",@"'$1'");
```

This example puts single quotes around all words and seperates them with commas.

To answer the comment below, here it is for notepad++

Put (\w+) in the find, and '$1' in the replace and hit "replace all"

Comment: OP asks for a Notepad++ solution.